# Display each Array element in loop

Tags: arrays, javascript-objects

I have a evt object which contains 4 array element. Array 1, Array and Array 2. [image]
Any idea how to run a loop and display all these arrays?

I tried with

```
for (let i = 0; i < evt.length; i++) {
                   
}
```

but inside this how to display each array I am not sure.

Comment: Please do not povide "code" in form of images. It makes it hard for everyone to understand and process your problem. Use the SO snippet editor instead and provide an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have an array of arrays of arrays. The simplest way to quickly get a "print-out" of all elements would be to turn the whole thing into a JSON string:

```js
const evt=[[[1]],[[2]],[[3],[4]]];

console.log("direct output:",evt);

console.log("output as JSON string:",JSON.stringify(evt))
```

If, on the other hand, you are only interested in a "flat" listing of all contained elements (regardless of their inner structure) you could do a `.flat()` over the array:

```js
const evt=[[[1]],[[2]],[[3],[4]]];

console.log(evt.flat(2))
```

You need to provide the argument `2` to the `.flat()` method as it would otherwise only flatten the array by one level.